# Array of UIButtons, got error: "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value"

Tags: ios, swift

I try to call the `startGame()` method in the subclass, however, it seems the `nButton` is not initialized.

And the error is

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value.

---

#### Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var startButton: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet var nButton: Array<UIButton>?
    @IBOutlet var overLable: UILabel?

    func indexOf(buttonToFind:UIButton,array:Array<UIButton>)->Int
    {
        var count = 0
        for item in array
        {
            if(buttonToFind != item)
            {
                count++
            }
            else
            {
                break
            }
        }
        return count
    }

    var deck = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25",]
    var next = 0

    @IBAction func pressButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
        var buttonIndex  = indexOf(sender, array: nButton!)
        if(sender.titleLabel.text != deck[next])
        {
            overLable!.text = "Game Over"
            time.invalidate()
            presentViewController((self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("container")) as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        else
        {
            overLable!.text = "Go on"
            next++
        }
        for(var i=0; i<25; i++)
        {
            nButton![i].enabled=((next<25))
        }

        if(next==25)
        {
            overLable!.text = "Congratulations"
            presentViewController((self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("container")) as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    var count = 20
    var time = NSTimer()

    @IBAction func start(sender: UIButton)
    {
        startGame()
        startButton!.enabled = (startButton!.titleLabel.text == "Start")
    }

    func update()
    {
        startButton!.setTitle("\(count--)", forState: UIControlState())
        //timeLable2.text = "\((count--)%10)"
        if(count < 0)
        {
            time.invalidate()
            overLable!.text = "Game Over"
        }
    }

    func startGame()
    {
        var number = [UInt32]()

        func displayNumber(index:Int) -> UInt32
        {
            for( var i = 0; i<100; i++)
            {
                var num = 0
                var inta = arc4random()%25+1
                for item in number
                {
                    if(inta == item)
                    {
                        num++
                    }
                }
                if(num==0)
                {
                    number.append(inta)
                }
            }
            return number[index]
        }

        for (var i = 0; i<25; i++ )
        {
            //HERE IS THE ERROR...
            nButton![i].setTitle("\(displayNumber(i))", forState: UIControlState())
        }

        overLable!.text=""
        next = 0

        for(var i=0; i<25; i++)
        {
            nButton![i].enabled=(next==0)
        }

        time.invalidate()
        count = 30

        time = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: ("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

#### The ContainerVC class:

```
import UIKit

class ContainerViewController: ViewController
{
    @IBAction func restartButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        super.startGame()
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows how to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood it: nButton[i] must be a reference outlet to a UIButton in the matching .xib file. Because you have created the buttons in the interface builder for a board game.

Did you stop at the line with the debugger and `po nButton[i]` (and to make sure also check that the nButton array is also not nil)?

I can not see that you are allocating an Array for nButton. Like `self.nButton = Array<UIButton>()`.

If you have allocated the Array anywhere else, I also can not see that you add all the buttons to the nButton array.

---

*nButton as a name for an Array of buttons is confusing ;-).*

---

The `indexOf` method is maybe not needed, as you could simply add every button a `tag` (a number). Which can easily be set in the interface builder. Maybe you don't even need the array then anymore.

[image]

Then you could check the index with tag like so:

```
switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        //index of button is one, do something
    default:
        //index of button is not relevant do nothing
}
```

Comment: The nButton is an IBOutlet collection which is created by control drag all the 25 buttons on my storyboard to the VC. The problem is, if I did not add the "super.startGame()"in the subclass, the app runs perfectly. Now I want the app to pop out another VC when the game either wins or loses. So probably the array is set to nil after the new VC is popped out? I just want to re-executing the code in the super class after pressing the restart button in the subclass.

Comment: @Gellert But how do you add the new view & viewController. There are many ways, some are deallocating the old view, some not (one way is `modal`). I changed my answer, maybe you don't need the array in the code if you use the `tag`

Comment: presentViewController((self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("container")) as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Yeah you destroy the old ViewController by exchanging it with the new one. You want to push the new ViewController or simply add the view of the other viewController (`viewController.addSubview(newViewcontroller.view)`). Every time you use that method a new instance of the ViewController will be created, presented and the old one deallocated and with it all the properties attached to it, like the collection and the buttons.